# Some vs Little Water in specific cases

Tags: politeness, determiners, exam-questions

I have always used the phrase "some water" and "a little water" interchangeably. Recently I took an English quiz and the question was :

> **Please give me** (*a little / some*) _____ **water to drink.**

I marked 'some' as the correct answer but found out that 'a little' was correct. Searching similar sentences on Google also confirms this. Is the use of 'some' here incorrect?

PS: I found many sentences where 'some' is used in this construction :

> Please, may I have some water in a cup

Is there any reason for using the specific phrase in that context?

Comment: “A little” implies a restriction on the amount of water requested. Both are grammatical though.

Comment: The tester will have to explain to hundreds of millions of native speakers who would say "some water" why  they are wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's hyper politeness, i.e. you're supposed to be humble and only request a little? I wonder where the OP found it.

Comment: @user2684291 Thanks for the response folks! I found the question in an exam for legal studies in India. (Question number 21) http://admission.aglasem.com/ailet-2013-question-papers-with-answer-key/ Also checked in multiple websites, all of which agreed on the same answer and googling the first also showed more results. Thus, I wanted to know if there's an obscure rule regarding this.

Comment: I noticed a mistake in question 23: they mark as correct the noun "parasite" when the adjective "parasitic" is indicated. I suspect this is just another example of a test created by recent grads with little experience in the field and inflicted on hapless applicants who have no form of redress.

Comment: apparently, the tester himself failed this question. I prefer to use "some"

Comment: @ahmad, why did you approve a spam edit?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Which one?

Comment: @Ahmad: http://ell.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/10431

Comment: @NathanTuggy I see, which links are allowed? for example sometimes people link to google or ngram or dictionaries...

Comment: @Ahmad: Well, *not spam links*! That site looks like an aggregator (in other words, an SEO spam farm), and the edit was completely nonsensical, doing nothing but stuffing a random link in a random spot. Also, the edit summary was exactly the same as the added text, link markup and all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thank you, I see, I try to consider this more.

Comment: @user2684291: Being humble and polite has nothing to do with learning the language. You should be able to use a language to express what you want to express. If you want to be rude then you should know how to express that properly, that is rudely. BTW. "Can I have some water to drink" is perfectly polite.

Comment: @gnasher729 I apologize; the first part of my sentence expands into “Maybe they're looking for *hyper politeness*.”, which is my attempt at trying to understand why someone would cross out an (absent context) acceptable choice. As for the *BTW* bit — see Marie-Lou A's answer. She explains what I assumed but haven't expounded on here.

Answer (score 0):

> Please give me (a little / some) _____ water to drink.

Both "**a little** water" and "**some** water" are perfectly correct, and they have very similar meanings. The expression "a little" does not refer to a tiny quantity of water, its meaning is closer to "some" than "not much".

> [English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/little-a-little-few-a-few)
>
> (**A) little and (a) few are quantifiers meaning ‘some’**. *Little* and *few* have negative meanings. We use them to mean ‘not as much as may be expected or wished for’.
>
> She saves **a little** money every month | some, a small amount
>
> <sub>Source: *Cambridge Dictionary*</sub>

However, when asking for "a little water" the speaker's tone will be slightly hesitant, and *some* speakers retain that this choice of expression is more polite, and less direct than simply saying

> Please give me **some** water...

The fact that the request is prefaced with *please* suggests that the examiner (or the author of the quiz) was looking for the more hesitant expression, i.e. *a little*.

Opinions may vary on this interpretation.

Answer (score -3):

*Some* indicates an indefinite amount.  This is clearly a valid way to refer to a liquid in English.

If you are required to drink a definite quantity of water then perhaps *a little* makes sense relative to that preordained volume.

Otherwise *a little* is *a little* too specific an answer to require of test-takers in good faith.

I haven't heard of nor have I detected any hypothetical natural water unit.

Unless we are talking about water on the molecular scale--but is that single molecule really  a little water?