# Can we say "little salty"?

Tags: sentence-usage, parts-of-speech

"The soup is a little salty" - means the soup is saltier than the average. I heard this before so I guess it is correct. What is the part of speech of "a little"?

Can we say "the soup is little salty", meaning that the soup is not salty enough? Also, what is the part of speech of "little"?

Comment: We can say that a fact is "little known" but we do not say that soup is "little salty".  The soup is *a little salty*.  You can be "a little sleepy" but not "little sleepy". "Little" without the article means "hardly".  "Little" with the article means "too" or "excessively".

Comment: "a little" can also mean slightly - "a little foggy" probably means a small amount of fog (contrast "very foggy").  A sentence that is completely changed by the presence of "a" is `There will be a little rain in the morning."

Comment: related: [Some vs Little Water in specific cases](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87554/some-vs-little-water-in-specific-cases)

Comment: @TRomano You mentioned that  "Little" with the article means "too" or "excessively". This contrast with what I know that "a little" means "slightly".

Comment: @user2720402:  "a little salty" means "it has more salt than it should have" or "it has more salt than I would like it to have". The salt content exceeds some threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soup is a little salty.

The sentence is grammatical; you can use "a little" as an adverb to mean slightly or to a small degree in front of the adjective salty. This usage is a little formal.  You can use "a bit" instead in informal spoken English.

On the other hand, you cannot use "little" with the adjective salty.  You don't use it with an adjective except for some adjectives. A couple of examples are as follows:

He's little known as a journalist.

His voice was little more/better than a whisper. (The Free Dictionary)

Comment: Try as I may, I can't find a reason why "little salty" should violate grammar when "little known" and "little more" don't. What is safe to say is that "little X", with *little* adverbially modifying *X*, is totally unidiomatic in most but a few well-known cases. As a result, people will hear your "the soup is little salty" as "the soup is **a** little salty", by way of auditory interpolation, and apologize instead of passing you the salt.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we say "the soup is little salty", meaning that the soup is not salty enough?

No, we cannot because the adjective **salty** already means: *tasting of, containing, or preserved with salt.* Moreover, "little" and "bit" are   normally used with the indefinite article  with adjectives, their function is to "soften" a statement; e.g. *a little hot*, *a bit spicy*, and *a little bit strong*. Without the article, *little*, *few*, and *bit*, carry a more  negative meaning; e.g. *I have **little** money* (I don't have much money) vs. *I have **a little** money* (I have 'some' money).

If I say a drink, or a snack is **[sugary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sugary)**, I am stating that it contains enough sugar for it to be noticeable.
**A bit sugary** suggests that I consider it to be on the sweet side. 
Colloquially, native speakers also say something is "a little bit sweet".

**Too much sugar** means it is *too sweet* for my [taste buds](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/taste-buds), some might  describe it as **[sickly-sweet](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/sickly-sweet)**; therefore, the expressions ***a little sugary*** means something is on the sweet side, and overly sweet. Similarly, ***a little salty*** means it contains enough amount of excessive salt for it to be "spoilt".

"A little salty" could also be a gross understatement, or used in polite company. In thie former case, the speaker could be implying that the food is almost [inedible](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inedible), but only context will tell us for sure what the real situation is.

To suggest that food is lacking in salt, we can say it in several ways,  using the NOUN **salt**

1. This needs more salt
2. The salt is missing
3. There is not enough salt
4. There is too little salt
5. There is **little salt**

What do we call "a bit", "a little bit", etc? The [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/mitigators) website tells us that they are known as **mitigators**, others say: **hedging**, or **approximators**.

> **Mitigators are the opposite of intensifiers** ...
>   We use these words and phrases as *mitigators*:
>
> **a bit** - **just a bit** - **a little** - **a little bit** - **just a little bit** - **rather** - **slightly**

References

1. *[Could you please tell me the difference between

   **a little**, **a little bit** and **a bit** with related examples?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv203.shtml)*
2. [Articles, Determiners, and Quantifiers](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/determiners/determiners.htm)
3. [Little, a little, few, a few](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/little-a-little-few-a-few)
4. [Hedge Words](http://theeditorsblog.net/2010/11/18/hedge-words/)
5. [Hedging and Discourse](https://books.google.it/books?id=rAkyvD6GGqoC&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=%22a%20little%22%20%20%22a%20bit%22%20hedging&source=bl&ots=zd1F01caK7&sig=uiOozy5ywTmjfOIKiwHY1YCcUXA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ25Hf3qbQAhXIVxoKHSb4BsQQ6AEIOjAG#v=onepage&q=%22a%20little%22%20%20%22a%20bit%22%20hedging&f=false)
6. <sub>[SOFTENING CRITICISM: THE USE OF LEXICAL HEDGES

   IN ACADEMIC SPOKEN INTERACTION](http://www.helsinki.fi/englanti/elfa/ProGradu_Niina_Riekkinen.pdf) pp 50,57,58</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I believe "a little" is an adverb of extent in the same way that "a lot" is.

"The soup is little salty." does not sound correct to me (and I'm quite confident it is not grammatical).  If I heard it, I would not know whether the speaker meant that the soup was too salty or wasn't salty enough.

A possible source of confusion might be what TRomano brought up in the comments.  The expression "little known" is common and completely grammatical.  This is because "known" is behaving as a noun in this context and "little" is modifying it as an adjective.

A seemingly valid way to think about it is that "a little" is an adverb form of "little".